# BeautifulSoup doesn't display the content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to scrape spot price data from MCX India website. 
The HTML script as visible on inspecting an element is as follows:

```html
<div class="contents spotmarketprice">
            <div id="cont-1" style="display: block;">
                <table class="mcx-table mrB20" width="100%" cellspacing="8" id="tblSMP">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="symbol-head">
                                Commodity
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Unit
                            </th>
                            <th class="left1">
                                Location
                            </th>
                            <th class="right1">
                                Spot Price (Rs.)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Up/Down
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="symbol" style="width:30%;">ALMOND</td>
                          <td style="width:17%;">1 KGS</td>
                          <td align="left" style="width:17%;">DELHI</td>
                          <td align="right" style="width:17%;">558.00</td>  

                          <td align="right" class="padR20" style="width:19%;">=</td>                                         
                      </tr>
```

**The code I have written is:**

```
#import the required libraries    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Getting data from website
source= requests.get('http://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price').text

#Getting the html code of the website
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#Navigating to the blocks where required content is present
division_1= soup.find('div', class_="contents spotmarketprice").div.table

#Displaying the results
print(division_1.tbody)
```

**Output:**

```
<tbody>
   </tbody>
```

On the website, the content that I want to get is available in ... But, it is not showing any content here. Please, suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd


goal = ['EnSymbol', 'Unit', 'Location', 'TodaysSpotPrice']

def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = json.loads(re.search(r'"Data":(\[.*?\])', r.text).group(1))
    allin = []
    for item in match:
        allin.append([item[x] for x in goal])
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=goal)
    print(df)


main("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price")
```

Output:

```
         EnSymbol     Unit    Location  TodaysSpotPrice
0          ALMOND    1 KGS       DELHI           558.00
1       ALUMINIUM    1 KGS       THANE           137.60
2        CARDAMOM    1 KGS  VANDANMEDU          2525.00
3      CASTORSEED  100 KGS       DEESA          3626.00
4           CHANA  100 KGS       DELHI          4163.00
5          COPPER    1 KGS       THANE           388.30
6          COTTON  1 BALES      RAJKOT         15880.00
7             CPO   10 KGS      KANDLA           635.90
8        CRUDEOIL    1 BBL      MUMBAI          2418.00
9            GOLD  10 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         40989.00
10     GOLDGUINEA   8 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         32923.00
11          GOLDM  10 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         40989.00
12      GOLDPETAL   1 GRMS      MUMBAI          4129.00
13        GUARGUM  100 KGS     JODHPUR          5880.00
14       GUARSEED  100 KGS     JODHPUR          3660.00
15          KAPAS   20 KGS      RAJKOT           927.50
16           LEAD    1 KGS     CHENNAI           141.60
17      MENTHAOIL    1 KGS   CHANDAUSI          1295.10
18     NATURALGAS  1 mmBtu      HAZIRA           138.50
19         NICKEL    1 KGS       THANE           892.00
20         PEPPER  100 KGS       KOCHI         32700.00
21       RAW JUTE  100 KGS     KOLKATA          4999.00
22  RBD PALMOLEIN   10 KGS      KANDLA           700.40
23      REFSOYOIL   10 KGS      INDORE           845.25
24         SILVER    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00
25        SILVERM    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00
26      SILVERMIC    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00
27      SUGARMDEL  100 KGS       DELHI          3380.00
28      SUGARMKOL  100 KGS    KOLHAPUR          3334.00
29      SUGARSKLP  100 KGS    KOLHAPUR          3275.00
30            TIN    1 KGS      MUMBAI          1160.50
31          WHEAT  100 KGS       DELHI          1977.50
32           ZINC    1 KGS       THANE           155.15
```

In case if you want to have the symbol of changes:

Here's the version of it:

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd


goal = ['EnSymbol', 'Unit', 'Location', 'TodaysSpotPrice', 'Change']


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = json.loads(re.search(r'"Data":(\[.*?\])', r.text).group(1))
    allin = []
    for item in match:
        item = [item[x] for x in goal]
        item[-1] = '▲' if item[-1] > 0 else '▼' if item[-1] < 0 else "="
        allin.append(item)
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=goal)
    print(df)


main("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price")
```

Output:

```
         EnSymbol     Unit    Location  TodaysSpotPrice Change
0          ALMOND    1 KGS       DELHI           558.00      =
1       ALUMINIUM    1 KGS       THANE           137.60      =
2        CARDAMOM    1 KGS  VANDANMEDU          2525.00      =
3      CASTORSEED  100 KGS       DEESA          3626.00      =
4           CHANA  100 KGS       DELHI          4163.00      =
5          COPPER    1 KGS       THANE           388.30      =
6          COTTON  1 BALES      RAJKOT         15880.00      ▲
7             CPO   10 KGS      KANDLA           635.90      ▲
8        CRUDEOIL    1 BBL      MUMBAI          2418.00      ▲
9            GOLD  10 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         40989.00      =
10     GOLDGUINEA   8 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         32923.00      =
11          GOLDM  10 GRMS   AHMEDABAD         40989.00      =
12      GOLDPETAL   1 GRMS      MUMBAI          4129.00      =
13        GUARGUM  100 KGS     JODHPUR          5880.00      =
14       GUARSEED  100 KGS     JODHPUR          3660.00      =
15          KAPAS   20 KGS      RAJKOT           927.50      ▲
16           LEAD    1 KGS     CHENNAI           141.60      =
17      MENTHAOIL    1 KGS   CHANDAUSI          1295.10      =
18     NATURALGAS  1 mmBtu      HAZIRA           138.50      ▲
19         NICKEL    1 KGS       THANE           892.00      =
20         PEPPER  100 KGS       KOCHI         32600.00      ▼
21       RAW JUTE  100 KGS     KOLKATA          4999.00      =
22  RBD PALMOLEIN   10 KGS      KANDLA           700.40      ▼
23      REFSOYOIL   10 KGS      INDORE           845.25      =
24         SILVER    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00      =
25        SILVERM    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00      =
26      SILVERMIC    1 KGS   AHMEDABAD         36871.00      =
27      SUGARMDEL  100 KGS       DELHI          3380.00      ▼
28      SUGARMKOL  100 KGS    KOLHAPUR          3334.00      ▲
29      SUGARSKLP  100 KGS    KOLHAPUR          3275.00      ▼
30            TIN    1 KGS      MUMBAI          1160.50      ▼
31          WHEAT  100 KGS       DELHI          1977.50      ▲
32           ZINC    1 KGS       THANE           155.15      =
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem like data within the table is being uploaded through JavaScript.

That's why, if you are trying to fetch this information using `requests` library, you don't receive table's data on return. `requests` simply doesn't support JS. Therefore, the problem here isn't in `BeautifulSoup`.

To scrape JS-driven data, consider using `selenium` and [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). The solution in this case will look like:

```py
# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# create a webdriver
chromedriver_path = 'C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

# go to the page and get its source
driver.get('http://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# fetch mentioned data
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tblSMP'})
for tr in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
    row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    print(row)

# close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

The output of the above script is:

```
['ALMOND', '1 KGS', 'DELHI', '558.00', '=']
['ALUMINIUM', '1 KGS', 'THANE', '137.60', '=']
['CARDAMOM', '1 KGS', 'VANDANMEDU', '2,525.00', '=']
['CASTORSEED', '100 KGS', 'DEESA', '3,626.00', '▼']
['CHANA', '100 KGS', 'DELHI', '4,163.00', '▲']
['COPPER', '1 KGS', 'THANE', '388.30', '=']
['COTTON', '1 BALES', 'RAJKOT', '15,790.00', '▲']
['CPO', '10 KGS', 'KANDLA', '630.10', '▼']
['CRUDEOIL', '1 BBL', 'MUMBAI', '2,418.00', '▲']
['GOLD', '10 GRMS', 'AHMEDABAD', '40,989.00', '=']
['GOLDGUINEA', '8 GRMS', 'AHMEDABAD', '32,923.00', '=']
['GOLDM', '10 GRMS', 'AHMEDABAD', '40,989.00', '=']
['GOLDPETAL', '1 GRMS', 'MUMBAI', '4,129.00', '=']
['GUARGUM', '100 KGS', 'JODHPUR', '5,880.00', '=']
['GUARSEED', '100 KGS', 'JODHPUR', '3,660.00', '=']
```

UPD: I must specify that the code above answers to the question of seeing this specific table. However, sometimes websites store data in 'application/json' or similar tags that can be reached with 'requests' library (since they don't require JS).

**As discovered by [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7), current website contains such tag. Please, check his answer. It is indeed better to use `requests`, than `selenium` in this situation.**

Comment: there's no need to use `selenium` at all, as it's even will slow down the task. even though, be informed that the data is actually within page source which is rendered dynamically from `script` tag.

Comment: @AyushSinha have a look on my answer